# How to re prompt user if he enters a character within a number?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program to ask a user an operation to be used and it will ask two numbers to work with. But if the user enters a number and there is a letter on it, the program should re-prompt the user to ask for another input.

```
 #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    void operation(int a);
    class Numbers{
        public:
            int num1, num2;
            float result;
    };
    int main(){
        Numbers input;
        int *ptr1 = &input.num1;
        int *ptr2 = &input.num2;
        float *ptr3 = &input.result;
        int range = 0;


        cout<<"Enter First Number: ";
        while(!(cin>>*(ptr1+range))){   
            cout<<"That's not a number!\n";
            cout<<"\nEnter First Number: ";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
        }
        cout<<"Enter Second Number: ";
        while(!(cin>>*(ptr1+range))){   
            cout<<"That's not a number!\n";
            cout<<"\nEnter Second Number: ";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
        }   
    }
```

So in this program when a user enters a character, it prompts the user to enter another one.
        But the problem is when I enter a letter within a number, the program does not re prompt but
        it jumps to the next line.

Enter First Number: t
    That's not a number!

```
Enter First Number: 4e      // as you can see, this is what happens, it did not reprompt but it jumped to the next line of code             
Enter Second Number: That's not a number!

Enter Second Number:
```

Comment: Have you tried ```e4``` ```e``` and ```44 34```?

Comment: @Melon  yes it works fine but when the number comes first it does not.

Comment: Great. Now as someone else pointed out, please use ```std::stoi``` Please check here how it works with examples, so you have a deeper understanding what is going on: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/). Basically it checks if the string is a digit or not, then you can use it in the while statement. Note that it should be checked on a character.

```
while (!isdigit(some_variable_that_gets_cin)) {
    ....
}
```

sample how to get the `cin`

```
char[10] number;
cin >> number;
isdigit(number);
ptr = <int> number;
```

Comment: so how can I change  while(!(cin>>*(ptr1+range))) to that?

Comment: ^ updated, you can stitch those codes snippets on your implementation.

Comment: should it be this way? while (!isdigit(*(ptr1+range))). It has a problem on first input. It runs the whole thing two times but on the third time it worked fine

Comment: well, nice that it worked fine on the third time. then I think once the logical position of your statements are correct, then your code should work perfectly.

Comment: When I entered "4e." The program did this: "Enter First Number: That's not a number!" and the next line ask for a number. When I entered 4e again it worked fine. So how can I fic it so it works fine on first try.

Comment: There is a problem, when I tried to enter a number, it runs the validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::stoi` to complete conversion check.

```
string number_string
cin >> number_string;
size_t number_end;
int number;
try {
    num = stoi(line, &number_end);
} catch (...) {
    // invalid number
}
if (number_end < line.size() && !isspace(line[number_end])) {
    // invalid number
}
```